# batch edit a PDF by adding a barcode based on text in the PDF?

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I receive around 30 workorders a day from my primary client.  They send them to me in a standardized report format, in a single PDF, with one page for each different workorder.  Unfortunately, these PDF reports dont include the workrorder_ID in a barcoded format, only in regular text font and they are unwilling to comply to my request to modify the report by adding a barcode.  Is there a way to automatically add a barcode to the PDF?  basically I would want the PDF editing  app to search for the text “workoder ID:” and to insert the barcode, beneath the work_order ID.
please advise. thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a PDF Library that includes a text extraction that includes reporting the location of each string extracted.  When you find the location of the Work Order ID text you can then use the same library add the barcode in correct position.   Quick PDF Library would be one option and iText be another.

http://www.quickpdflibrary.com

http://itextpdf.com

Disclaimer : I do some consulting for Quick PDF Library